# Query error handling in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I am trying to execute a MySQL query using the CI active record library. If the query is malformed, then CI invokes an internal server error 500 and quits without processing the next steps.

I need to roll back all the other queries processed before that error statement, and the roll back is also not happening.. can you help please?

The code snippets is as below:

```
function dbInsertInformationToDB($data_array)
{
    $returnID = "";
    $uniqueDataArray = array();

      // I prepare a array of values here
    $uniqueTableList = filter_unique_tables($data_array[2]);
    $this->db->trans_begin();

    // inserting is done here
    // when there is a query error in $this->db->insert().. it is not rolling back the previous query executed

    foreach($uniqueTableList as $table_name)
    {
        $uniqueDataArray = filterDataArray($data_array,$table_name,2);
        $this->db->insert($table_name,$uniqueDataArray);
        if ($this->db->_error_message())
        {
            $error = "I am caught!!";
        }
        $returnID = $this->db->affected_rows();
    }
    if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
    {
        $this->db->trans_rollback();
    }
    else
    {
        $this->db->trans_commit();
    }

    return "ERROR";
}
```

Comment: Make sure your table is InnoDB and not MyISAM.  MyISAM does not support transaction, so there is no rollback.  Do a SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename with your sql query.

Comment: Sounds likely to me, Yada. You should move this comment to an answer though otherwise it can't be accepted!

Comment: Yada, right. I changed the table type to InnoDB and it went well. One more issue now it, when the sql hits an error, CI throws an error page. It is not proceeding below where i can handle the error and show a meaningful message.. any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a try catch block: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php